# Intellisense not working for external libraries in Kotlin language server

Tags: kotlin, language-server-protocol, external-dependencies

For external libraries kotlin intellisense is not working. It is showing "Unresolved Reference" error.

I am trying to inject dependencies of Jackson jars to my Kotlin LSP. Can anyone suggest how we can achieve this?
[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuJ1h.png)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue using scripts, as described here https://github.com/fwcd/kotlin-language-server#figuring-out-the-dependencies